# LYX- Labelling Theorems,Lemmas

Tags: lyx

In one of the previous posts I posted here, you told me how to make the theorem numbering restart in every new section.

I now want that every theorem/lemma/claim will be of the form X.Y where X is the section and Y is the number of the theorem in this section.

Can someone tell me what is the command I need to enter in order to do this?

Comment: Did you see that? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45355/theorem-numbering-as-chapter-section-subsection-theorem-number

Comment: In LyX, you can do this by going to Document -> Settings -> Module and select the appropriate AMS modules.