# How to (progressively) number everything (paragraphs, definitions, theorems, remarks, examples, etc.) within a section

Tags: sectioning, formatting, numbering

My aim is to format a text according to the following guidelines:

[as a reference, please cf the pictures below, which are taken from *Jean-Michel Bony, Cours d'analyse, Ellipses ed. 2016*, actually from its 9th chapter]

1. the main numbered "units" are chapters and sections, and they both work as usual;
2. each section is made up of "parts" which should be numbered progressively in the form: `chapter#.section#.#`.
3. as a "part" of a section, one should be able to use different environments, such as theorem-like environments (for theorems, propositions, corollaries, lemmas, definitions, remarks, etc.), paragraph-like environments, etc.; each environment should be able to keep its "natural properties": for example the spacing before and after (so that the space before a paragraph is greater than the one before a theorem), or the title format (so that a "theorem" should start with `Theorem thm# (thmname).` (with "Theorem" *before* the number), everything bold; a paragraph with `par#. parname`, everything bold; an "exercise" with `Exercise exer#.`, italic; an "exemple" with `exem#. Exemple: exemname`, italic; etc.; each part number: `thm#`, `par#`, `exer#`, `exem#` should follow rule 2);
4. subsections are "numbered" by letters;
5. one should not be forced to number everything (such as in the last picture, where the "parts" *Conjugaison complexe et parité*, *Translation* and *Dilatation* appear to be spaced as each of them were a paragraph, but still they're not numbered).

Is there a simple way to do so? At least is there a simple way to set the same "counter" for everything?

PS: I apologize in advance whether my question is somewhat inappropriate and or ill-formulated; this is my first question ever, please be patient…

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

[image: 5]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that for theorems, exercises and other environments of the `amsthm` package, you will find solutions here: [Theorem numbering as chapter.section.subsection.theorem number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45355/158599). More formatting options for theorem titles will be in [`amsthm`'s doc](http://distrib-coffee.ipsl.jussieu.fr/pub/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/required/amscls/doc/amsthdoc.pdf).

"Parts" of sections should be "subsections" to me. You can change their numbering format (A, B, C) by adding this to your preamble: `\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}}`.
To add a dot at the end of all ((sub)sub)sections's number, check this out: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24440/158599.

If you don't want to number a "part" (chapter, section, subsection, etc.), just use its starred version. For instance: `\section*{My section}` instead of `\section{My section}`. For more advanced formatting, I recommend to use the [`titlesec`](http://www.texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/titlesec/titlesec.pdf) package.

However, the "Dilatation", "Translation" paragraphs etc. rather seem to be unnumbered `amsthm` environments. Check out the [`amsthm`'s doc](http://distrib-coffee.ipsl.jussieu.fr/pub/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/required/amscls/doc/amsthdoc.pdf) to see how to create your unnumbered environment with your customized theorem style (p. 3 and § 4.3, p. 9).

Comment: Thanks a lot. So let me see if I correctly got your point: (1) I have to define a set of theoremlike environments; for example, in order to match the pictures output, I have to set at least one for each of the following head styles: i. bold, italic, name before # (eg Theoreme et definition 9.1.1.); ii. roman, bold, # before name (eg 9.1.2. Transformees des function gaussiene); iii. italic, name before # (eg Exercise 9.1.3); iv. italic, # before name (eg 9.4.5. Exemple: Transformee de Fourier de 1). Then (2) I have to enter my text as a sequence of these "theorems", all with the same counter.

Comment: (1) Yes. You may also have to create a theorem style (or environment) for unnumbered theorems ("translation", "dilatation").
(2) Yes.